# How to get Biopython to work with spyder + avoid command prompt

Tags: python, installation, package, spyder, biopython

I'm using a computer with admin restrictions. I can't install python to the command line because I hit the admin login wall, but I could install spyder to practice basic python scripts. Is there a way to install biopython without using command prompt and if so how do I get it to work with Spyder. In spyder I have tried import Bio and pip install biopython in spyder. Neither has worked. So any advice on getting these two to work together without hitting the admin lock? Our IT team hasn't been super helpful with getting stuff like this working in the past...

Comment: Maybe you could try installing anaconda/miniconda for just your user (I think you don't need admin rights for that type of installation). The Spyder standalone installer version only comes with a subset of packages like numpy, pandas and matplotlib bundled. To use other packages you will need to have a way to create envs and use the custom interpreter preference. For more info you on that can check here: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer

Answer (score 1):

You can install biopython thereby you watch below video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r66YCsA4YqM